# How to normalize state in apollo-link-state?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, graphql-js, apollo-client

Given a query that returns a response with many levels, for example this query on [Github's GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/):

```
query {
  viewer {
    starredRepositories(first: 100) {
      edges {
        node {
          repositoryTopics(first: 100) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                topic {
                  id
                  name
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**How can you normalize the topics and store it into a store using [`apollo-link-state`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/state.html)?**

```
{
  topics: [Topic]
}
```

Currently my store is set up as follows:

```js
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';
import { withClientState } from 'apollo-link-state';

const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const store = withClientState({
  cache,
  defaults: {
    topics: [],
  },
  resolvers: {},
  typeDefs: `
    type Topic {
      id: String!
      name: String!
    }

    type Query {
      topics: [Topic]
    }
  `,
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  links: ApolloLink.from([
    // Other links ... ,
    store,
    // Other links ... ,
  ]),
});
```

Inspecting my cache shows the `ROOT_QUERY`:

```
{
  topics: { ... },
  viewer: User
    starredRepositories({"first":100}): StarredRepositoryConnection
      ...
}
```

As well as all the entities [normalized by `apollo-cache-inmemory`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#normalization).

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding normalizing data is completely outside of the scope of Apollo queries or cache. You're going to want to create some sort of helper function to flatten the object as needed once it has been fetched from the cache. Unlike Redux there isn't middleware where an action can be processed on it and stored in cache. At least to my knowledge. I did find [graphql_normalizr](https://github.com/monojack/graphql-normalizr) which might give you what you want though. For me I would stick with simply wrapping the Query in a component with a helper function to run the fetched object through a normalized schema via [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/issues/108 before being returned.

Comment: However, proceed with caution. In apollo-client land data has direct bindings to ui so changing data structures for your ui could come back to bite you as you are breaking that contract.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I partly agree with your statement about normalisation being out of scope of the cache; however normalization is done by [`apollo-cache-inmemory`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#normalization). The problem is the shape of the store and accessing this normalised data; I couldn't find any documentation this. You bringing up the comparison with Redux and mentioning the direct bindings with UI gave me a thought: am I trying to model everything as if I was building with Redux? Is there anything I need to 'unlearn' from Redux to get Apollo?

Comment: Well there certainly isn't middleware hooks. I would assume the best way to deal with normalization is wrap your Query in a component where the output could be normalized in a way the UI could use. However, to my point above perhaps you should weigh the cost of normalizing data vs iterating over non-normalized data.